# jQuery selector: selecting the body tag of an iframe

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup that will be repeated for several questions

```
<p id="questionOne">What are your tasks?</p>

<p id="copyLastYear"><a href="#">Copy from last year</a></p>

<div id="anserOne">
  <div class="cleditorMain">
    <div><!-- Editor tags here --></div>
    <iframe>
      <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

When someone clicksthe copy from last year link I need to set the html in the body with the details from last years answer.

The problem I'm having is selecting the body tag

I tried the following but with no luck

```
$('#answerOne .cleditorMain iframe html body').html('<p>New HTML value</p>');
```

Can anyone help with the selector part of this please.

Comment: In your HTML "answerOne" is mis-spelt.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. That was some pseudo code that I typed in, but often it is the little spelling mistakes that never get noticed.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). Something like this should work.

```
$('#answerOne .cleditorMain iframe').contents().find('body').html('<p>New HTML value</p>');
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm.

Thank you vey much for your help.